# Why show incorrect result with php function?

Tags: php

Why show incorrect result with php function ?

This is my code. It's must to show `0`

But when i test this code. It's show `99`

Why ?????

```
<?PHP
$first = "8.12";
$second = "0.12";
$first = ($first)*(100);
$second = ($second)*(100);
$results = ($first)-($second);
echo ($results)%(100);
?>
```

Comment: When working with float values, use the `fmod()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a weird issue with floating point variables (double). Here's how you can fix it without worrying about casting variables:

```
$first = "8.12";
$second = "0.12";
$first = ($first)*(100);
$second = ($second)*(100);
$results = round(($first)-($second));
echo ($results)%(100);
```

Adding [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to the results calculation (or, if you want, when multiplying `$first` and `$second` with 100) will solve the floating point error.

You can also specify the precision of `round()` with a second argument, such as

```
round(123.4567, 2); // 123.46
```